# How to fix MadMAx Plotter not installed error on chia Blockchain

Tags: command-line

Recently I stared Mining(Farming Chia plots after 1.5 weeks of wallet sync;

1. I am using Ubuntu-22.04 (Running Natively on a SSD)
2. Chia Blockchain version 1.5.1 (started framing about 4 days).

Recently I had a notification on the Ubuntu showing up a system update notification (which included an update for chia) and I updated and restarted the system. After that the Chia BlockChain started showing the MadMAx plotter was not installed when plotting a new plot. I tried uninstalling the Chia BlockChian app and reinstalling it, and tried various command shown on the internet to install the madmax plotter, but I was not able to resolve it.

I am not sure what to do, please someone help me. I have included the image of the list of plotters shown in the chia app. [Click here to enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN46C.png)

Website Links I have visited:

1. https://www.incredigeek.com/home/how-to-install-madmax-plotter-on-ubuntu-20-04/
2. https://chiaforum.com/t/1-2-11-missing-mad-max-plotter-in-list/14645

Thank You very much,

Eagerly Waiting for your replay,

Comment: Didi you try https://chiaforum.com/t/1-2-11-missing-mad-max-plotter-in-list/14645/2 ?

Comment: Thanks for your replay,

I have already tried that command line, but it did not install the madmax plotter and it kept showing; it was not installed and I wasn't able to upload it it in the ask ubuntu and stack overflow website, So I made a compline in the official chia GitHub repository and please visit this link which will guide you to the GitHub repository of chia and to the issue section for further details; https://github.com/Chia-Network/chia-blockchain/issues/13326.